# Segregating data from different collections in Neo4j database community edition

Tags: neo4j

This might be a simple question but I haven't been able to find the best practice on how to create different collections within a Neo4j database. I have data that comes from different countries and its better if I keep them segregated for multiple reasons. Common sense tells they should be different isolated databases or collections. As far as I could tell each Neo4j spawn supports just one database. This is a problem especially if I have to automate which isolated collection has to be invoked depending on the user request, unless of course if I host multiple Neo4j instances all at the same time somehow. How have other people navigated this situation.